# How to play from mic to speakers in Ubuntu Karmic?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, audio, microphone

Ok, I have a silly problem. I have few bluetooth headsets lying around and I want to make DIY baby monitor out of them. All I need is for some application to listen to the mic and send it to the speakers.
Loopback (even though it doesn't work) is not good enough, it'll send sound from the mic to the speakers in the same device but I need it to go across devices.
So does anyone know some application that can do that? I'm looking for something small and easy to use, not jackd or similar.

Comment: Sweet idea.  Wish I had this available a couple of years ago.  Coulda used this (and solutions) myself.

Comment: Just tried it, wasn't such a good idea it seems. Work nice with one bluetooth headset but with two I get a about a minute delay and everything is slow. Turns out you just can't listen to A2DP on one headset and listen to the mic on the other, either BT controller is not good enough or bluez stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using PulseAudio then you can use `pacat` to make a loop between two different devices:

```
pacat -r -d alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo | pacat -p -d bluez_sink.00_19_XX_XX_XX_XX
```

You can use `paman` to get the source and sink device names.

Comment: Tried with two different bluetooth adapters each paired with it's own headset. That kind of setup works flawlessly. By the way, one can easily do `pacat -r | pacat -p` and then select input and output from PulseAudio Volume Control tool, it is easier than finding out what names devices have.

Comment: To reduce latency, you can use `pacat -r | pacat -p --latency-msec=1`